# How to convert NTP time to Unix Epoch time in C language (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, epoch, ntp

I have been trying for several months to create a simple SNTP single Client/Server based on [RFC5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905). Finally I manage to make it work at least I think it works correctly, but when I tried to test my code against a real NTP server (e.g. 0.se.pool.ntp.org:123) the timestamps that I am receiving need to be recalculated. I have tried several different approaches but no matter for 3 days now but no matter what I tried nothing yet.

Does anybody know how to convert the NTP timestamp to Unix epoch timestamp?

Syntax to execute the Server e.g. ./server 127.0.0.1:5000 and Client e.g. ./client 127.0.0.1:5000

Syntax to execute the Client against a real NTP server e.g. ./client 0.se.pool.ntp.org:123

Sample of working code Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define UNIX_EPOCH 2208988800UL /* 1970 - 1900 in seconds */

typedef struct client_packet client_packet;
struct client_packet {
  uint8_t client_li_vn_mode;
  uint8_t client_stratum;
  uint8_t client_poll;
  uint8_t client_precision;
  uint32_t client_root_delay;
  uint32_t client_root_dispersion;
  uint32_t client_reference_identifier;
  uint32_t client_reference_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_reference_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t client_originate_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_originate_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t client_receive_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_receive_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t client_transmit_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_transmit_timestamp_microsec;
}__attribute__((packed));

typedef struct server_send server_send;
struct server_send {
  uint8_t server_li_vn_mode;
  uint8_t server_stratum;
  uint8_t server_poll;
  uint8_t server_precision;
  uint32_t server_root_delay;
  uint32_t server_root_dispersion;
  char server_reference_identifier[4];
  uint32_t server_reference_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_reference_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t server_originate_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_originate_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t server_receive_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_receive_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t server_transmit_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_transmit_timestamp_microsec;
}__attribute__((packed));

/* Linux man page bind() */
#define handle_error(msg)               \
  do {perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} while (0)

uint32_t ClockGetTime() {
  struct timespec ts;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
  return (uint32_t)ts.tv_sec * 1000000LL + (uint32_t)ts.tv_nsec / 1000LL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int sockfd , numbytes;
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
  int rv;

  client_packet memsend;
  server_send memrcv;
  
  memset( &memsend , 0 , sizeof memsend );
  memset( &memrcv , 0 , sizeof memrcv );

    char IP[16]; /* IP = 15 digits 1 extra for \0 null terminating character string */

    char PORT_STR[6]; /* Port = 5 digits MAX 1 extra for \0 null terminating character string */

    memset(IP , '\0' , sizeof(IP));
    memset(PORT_STR , '\0' , sizeof(PORT_STR));

    strcpy(IP, strtok(argv[1], ":"));
    strcpy(PORT_STR, strtok(NULL, ":"));
    
    memset( &hints , 0 , sizeof hints );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ( ( rv = getaddrinfo( IP , PORT_STR , &hints , &servinfo ) ) != 0 ) {
      fprintf( stderr , "getaddrinfo: %s\n" , gai_strerror(rv) );
      return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for( p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next ) {
      if ( ( sockfd = socket( p->ai_family , p->ai_socktype , p->ai_protocol ) ) == -1 ) {
    handle_error( "socket" );
    continue;
      }
      break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error while binding socket\n");
      return 2;
    }

    memsend.client_li_vn_mode = 0b00100011;
    memsend.client_stratum = 0;
    memsend.client_poll = 0;
    memsend.client_precision = 0;
    memsend.client_root_delay = 0;
    memsend.client_root_dispersion = 0;
    memsend.client_reference_identifier = 0;
    memsend.client_reference_timestamp_sec = 0;
    memsend.client_reference_timestamp_microsec = 0;

    memsend.client_receive_timestamp_sec = 0;
    memsend.client_receive_timestamp_microsec = 0;

    time_t time_originate_sec = time(NULL);
    memsend.client_originate_timestamp_sec = time_originate_sec;
    memsend.client_originate_timestamp_microsec = ClockGetTime();

    memsend.client_transmit_timestamp_sec = memsend.client_originate_timestamp_sec;
    memsend.client_transmit_timestamp_microsec = memsend.client_originate_timestamp_microsec;
    
    if ( ( numbytes = sendto( sockfd, &memsend , sizeof memsend , 0 ,
                  p->ai_addr , p->ai_addrlen ) ) == -1 ) {
      handle_error("sendto");
      exit(1);
    }
  
    if ( ( numbytes = recvfrom( sockfd , &memrcv , sizeof memrcv , 0 ,
                (struct sockaddr *) &p->ai_addr, &p->ai_addrlen ) ) == -1 ) {
      handle_error( "recvfrom" );
      exit(1);
    }

    time_t time_rcv_sec = time(NULL);
    uint32_t client_rcv_timestamp_sec = time_rcv_sec;
    uint32_t client_rcv_timestamp_microsec = ClockGetTime();

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    char Identifier[5];
    memset(Identifier , '\0' , sizeof Identifier);
    memcpy(Identifier , memrcv.server_reference_identifier , sizeof memrcv.server_reference_identifier);

    printf("\t Reference Identifier \t %"PRIu32" \t\t\t %s\n",memsend.client_reference_identifier,Identifier);
    printf("\t Reference Timestamp \t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32" \t\t\t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32"\n",memsend.client_reference_timestamp_sec,memsend.client_reference_timestamp_microsec,memrcv.server_reference_timestamp_sec,memrcv.server_reference_timestamp_microsec);
    printf("\t Originate Timestamp \t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32" \t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32"\n",memsend.client_originate_timestamp_sec,memsend.client_originate_timestamp_microsec,memrcv.server_originate_timestamp_sec,memrcv.server_originate_timestamp_microsec);
    printf("\t Receive Timestamp \t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32" \t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32"\n",client_rcv_timestamp_sec,client_rcv_timestamp_microsec,memrcv.server_receive_timestamp_sec,memrcv.server_receive_timestamp_microsec);
    printf("\t Transmit Timestamp \t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32" \t %"PRIu32".%"PRIu32"\n\n",memsend.client_transmit_timestamp_sec,memsend.client_transmit_timestamp_microsec,memrcv.server_transmit_timestamp_sec,memrcv.server_transmit_timestamp_microsec);
  
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample of Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define TRUE 1

typedef struct client_send client_send;
struct client_send {
  uint8_t client_li_vn_mode;
  uint8_t client_startum;
  uint8_t client_poll;
  uint8_t client_precision;
  uint32_t client_root_delay;
  uint32_t client_root_dispersion;
  uint32_t client_reference_identifier;
  uint32_t client_reference_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_reference_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t client_originate_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_originate_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t client_receive_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_receive_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t client_transmit_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t client_transmit_timestamp_microsec;
}__attribute__((packed));

typedef struct server_packet server_packet;
struct server_packet {
  uint8_t server_li_vn_mode;
  uint8_t server_startum;
  uint8_t server_poll;
  uint8_t server_precision;
  uint32_t server_root_delay;
  uint32_t server_root_dispersion;
  char server_reference_identifier[4];
  uint32_t server_reference_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_reference_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t server_originate_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_originate_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t server_receive_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_receive_timestamp_microsec;
  uint32_t server_transmit_timestamp_sec;
  uint32_t server_transmit_timestamp_microsec;
}__attribute__((packed));

/* Linux man page bind() */
#define handle_error(msg)               \
  do {perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} while (0)

uint32_t ClockGetTime() {
  struct timespec ts;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
  return (uint32_t)ts.tv_sec * 1000000LL + (uint32_t)ts.tv_nsec / 1000LL;
}

unsigned long int precision() {

  struct timespec res;
  
  if ( clock_getres( CLOCK_REALTIME, &res) == -1 ) {
    perror( "clock get resolution" );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return res.tv_nsec / 1000;

}

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) {

  if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
  }

  return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  server_packet send_mem;
  client_send rcv_mem;

  /* Empty structs */
  memset( &send_mem , 0 , sizeof send_mem );
  memset( &rcv_mem , 0 , sizeof rcv_mem );

  char s[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
  struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
  socklen_t addr_len;
  int get, numbytes;
  int sockfd;

    char IP[16];

    char PORT_STR[6];

    memset(IP , '\0' , sizeof(IP));
    memset(PORT_STR , '\0' , sizeof(PORT_STR));

    strcpy(IP, strtok(argv[1], ":"));
    strcpy(PORT_STR, strtok(NULL, ":"));

    memset( &hints , 0 , sizeof hints );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

    if ( ( get = getaddrinfo( NULL , PORT_STR , &hints , &servinfo ) ) != 0) {
      fprintf( stderr , "getaddrinfo: %s\n" , gai_strerror(get) );
      return 1;
    }

    for( p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next ) {
      if ( ( sockfd = socket( p->ai_family , p->ai_socktype ,
                  p->ai_protocol ) ) == -1 ) {
    handle_error("socket");
    continue;
      }

      if ( bind( sockfd , p->ai_addr , p->ai_addrlen ) == -1 ) {
    close(sockfd);
    handle_error("bind");
    continue;
      }

      break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Not able to bind socket\n");
      return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    printf("\nServer is up and running: waiting to recv msg at port: %s...\n",
       PORT_STR);

    while(TRUE) {

      time_t t_ref_sec = time(NULL);
      unsigned long int Ref_epoc_sec = t_ref_sec;
      send_mem.server_reference_timestamp_sec = Ref_epoc_sec;

      unsigned long int t_ref_nanosec = ClockGetTime();
      send_mem.server_reference_timestamp_microsec = t_ref_nanosec;

      addr_len = sizeof(their_addr);

      if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, &rcv_mem , sizeof rcv_mem , 0,
                   (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
    handle_error("recvfrom");
    exit(1);
      }

      time_t t_rcv_sec = time(NULL);
      send_mem.server_receive_timestamp_sec = t_rcv_sec;
      send_mem.server_receive_timestamp_microsec = ClockGetTime();

      printf("Peer address: %s\n",
         inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
               get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
               s, sizeof(s)));

      printf("Peer port: %i\n",p->ai_socktype);

      send_mem.server_li_vn_mode = 0b00100100;
      send_mem.server_startum = 0b00000001;
      send_mem.server_poll = 0b00000110;
      send_mem.server_precision = precision();
      send_mem.server_root_delay = 0;
      send_mem.server_root_dispersion = 0;
      memcpy( send_mem.server_reference_identifier , "LOCL" , 
          sizeof send_mem.server_reference_identifier );
      send_mem.server_originate_timestamp_sec = rcv_mem.client_originate_timestamp_sec;
      send_mem.server_originate_timestamp_microsec = rcv_mem.client_originate_timestamp_microsec;
      time_t t_send_sec = time(NULL);
      send_mem.server_transmit_timestamp_sec = t_send_sec;
      send_mem.server_transmit_timestamp_microsec = ClockGetTime();

      if ( sendto( sockfd, &send_mem , sizeof send_mem , 0 ,
           (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr , addr_len ) == -1 ) {
    handle_error("sendto");
    exit(1);
      } 

    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample of printed output when I use Server and Client.

```
Reference Identifier     0                       LOCL
Reference Timestamp      0.0                     1426637081.3564398733
Originate Timestamp      1426637087.3570333925   1426637087.3570333925
Receive Timestamp        1426637087.3570334078   1426637087.3570334003
Transmit Timestamp       1426637087.3570333925   1426637087.3570334046
```

Sample of printed output when I am probing a real NTP server (e.g. 0.se.pool.ntp.org:123).

```
Reference Identifier     0                       �$�
Reference Timestamp      0.0                     3879449560.3503094062
Originate Timestamp      1426637090.3573978972   1426637090.3573978972
Receive Timestamp        1426637090.3573992772   2722083800.781009125
Transmit Timestamp       1426637090.3573978972   2722083800.937312997
```

The expected output would be something similar to print out as I posted before.

Thank you in advance for everyones time and effort to assist me.

**Update** Relevant question but not close to the answer that I am looking for [How to write a NTP client? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757575/how-to-write-a-ntp-client).

Comment: NTP uses an epoch of 1900-01-01 00:00:00, so the offset should be 2208988800 seconds. Leap seconds might be an issue. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Timestamps

Comment: Hello @KeithThompson, thank you for your time and effort. I tried also to add the leap seconds and after subtract the 2208988800 seconds but still the time it is far from close. But again thank you suggesting that.

Comment: The current NTP timestamp is 3635628531 seconds, which exceeds 2**31-1. Try using `int64_t` for the arithmetic.

Comment: @KeithThompson I did that ``int64_t T1 = memsend.client_transmit_timestamp_sec;
    T1 = T1 * 1000000LL /* microseconds */ + memsend.client_transmit_timestamp_microsec;`` for the calculation part also but still the numbers are not correct. I have not post these parts of my code here in order to avoid people comment negatively regarding irrelevant code. Again thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: The factor of one million (`1000000LL`) doesn't seem consistent with the NTP timestamp format, but I haven't looked closely at your code. (And I see the offset of `2208988800UL` was already in your code; I hadn't noticed that at first.)

Comment: Hello @KeithThompson, apologies for the late reply. The reason that I am using the factor one million is that I trying to convert a number to micro 10^(-6). As a second step I add that to the original number.

While I was reading even more, I found also another mistake that I have done. I have not converted the number with ``htonl() host to network long `` the ones that I am sending and ``ntohl() network to host long`` the ones that I am receiving. It might effect the reply to my server, I will apply it and I will post my results. Again thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Leap seconds are not considered when translating NTP timestamps to unix timestamps, as both times are UTC times.  UTC time is a continous monotone scale of seconds.  Leap seconds are considered when changing from atomic time to UTC or viceversa.

Comment: Hello @LuisColorado, you are absolutely right. Last night I manage to find the solution. I have not manage to complete it yet that is why I have not post the code yet. In general is the time that you receive (sec) - Epoch seconds.

Comment: @LuisColorado *Leap seconds are not considered when translating NTP timestamps to unix timestamps, as both times are UTC times. UTC time is a continuous monotone scale of seconds.* But actually, that's completely false!  UTC is *supposed* to take leap seconds into account.  The only reason you can ignore leap seconds when converting back and forth between Unix time and NTP time is that both of them, improperly, ignore leap seconds.

Comment: UTC contains timestamps such as 2016-12-31T23:59:60 which simply cannot be represented as a Unix or an NTP time.  (NTP does have some out-of-band ways of indicating leap seconds.)  The time scale that *is* continuous and monotonic, and does not have any leap seconds in it, is TAI.

Comment: They should be, as leap seconds are actually inserted in the UTC time scale.  The only scale that has no leap seconds is TAI (International Atomic Time scale) The specification of the standard system time in unix says that  leap seconds are ignored, which forces all unices time to be stepped when a leap second is inserted.  That's unfortunately a pity, as the local time conversion routines allows to consider leap seconds in the data base and adjust (and so have in consideration) leap second insertion (and so using TAI as internal time and deriving UTC from it, as it is done on every timezone)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

converting NTP timestamps to Unix timestamps (struct timeval) involves two problems to be solved.

One is the offset between the two epochs. Unix uses an epoch located at 1/1/1970-00:00h (UTC) and NTP uses 1/1/1900-00:00h.  This leads to an offset equivalent to 70 years in seconds (there are 17 leap years between the two dates so the offset is

```
(70*365 + 17)*86400 = 2208988800
```

to be substracted from NTP time to get Unix `struct timeval`.

The second is that `struct timeval` uses `1/1000000 sec` as unit of subsecond fractions and NTP uses `1/2^32 sec` as its unit of fractional time.  To convert from NTP to `struct timeval` one might divide the fractional part by `2^32` (this is easy, it's a right shift) and then multiply by `1000000`.  To cope with this, we have to use 64 bit arithmetic, as numbers range between `0` and `2^32` so, the best is:

- to convert from NTP to `struct timeval` copy the fractional part field (the right 32 bits of a NTP timestamp) to a `uint64_t` variable and multiply it by `1000000`, then right shift it by 32 bit positions to get the proper value.  You must take into account that NTP timestamps are in network byte order, so perhaps you'll have to make some adjustments to be able to operate with the numbers.
- To convert from `struct timeval` copy the `tv_usec` field of the unix time to a `uint64_t` and left shift it 32 bit positions, then divide it by  `1000000` and convert to network byte order (most significative byte first)

The following code sample illustrates this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#define OFFSET 2208988800ULL

void ntp2tv(uint8_t ntp[8], struct timeval *tv)
{
    uint64_t aux = 0;
    uint8_t *p = ntp;
    int i;

    /* we get the ntp in network byte order, so we must
     * convert it to host byte order. */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof ntp / 2; i++) {
        aux <<= 8;
        aux |= *p++;
    } /* for */

    /* now we have in aux the NTP seconds offset */
    aux -= OFFSET;
    tv->tv_sec = aux;

    /* let's go with the fraction of second */
    aux = 0;
    for (; i < sizeof ntp; i++) {
        aux <<= 8;
        aux |= *p++;
    } /* for */

    /* now we have in aux the NTP fraction (0..2^32-1) */
    aux *= 1000000; /* multiply by 1e6 */
    aux >>= 32;     /* and divide by 2^32 */
    tv->tv_usec = aux;
} /* ntp2tv */

void tv2ntp(struct timeval *tv, uint8_t ntp[8])
{
    uint64_t aux = 0;
    uint8_t *p = ntp + sizeof ntp;
    int i;

    aux = tv->tv_usec;
    aux <<= 32;
    aux /= 1000000;

    /* we set the ntp in network byte order */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof ntp/2; i++) {
        *--p = aux & 0xff;
        aux >>= 8;
    } /* for */

    aux = tv->tv_sec;
    aux += OFFSET;

    /* let's go with the fraction of second */
    for (; i < sizeof ntp; i++) {
        *--p = aux & 0xff;
        aux >>= 8;
    } /* for */

} /* ntp2tv */

size_t print_tv(struct timeval *t)
{
    return printf("%ld.%06ld\n", t->tv_sec, t->tv_usec);
}

size_t print_ntp(uint8_t ntp[8])
{
    int i;
    int res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof ntp; i++) {
        if (i == sizeof ntp / 2)
            res += printf(".");
        res += printf("%02x", ntp[i]);
    } /* for */
    res += printf("\n");
    return res;
} /* print_ntp */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timeval t;
    uint8_t ntp[8];

    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);

    printf("tv2ntp\n");
    tv2ntp(&t, ntp);
    printf("tv : "); print_tv(&t);
    printf("ntp: "); print_ntp(ntp);

    printf("ntp2tv\n");
    ntp2tv(ntp, &t);
    printf("tv : "); print_tv(&t);
    printf("ntp: "); print_ntp(ntp);
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, also in order to complete my answer to my problem you need also to convert the int from network byte order to byte order. This can be accomplished with the help of htons(), htonl(), ntohs(), ntohl(). Again thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @Thanos, It is being converted, but not using the htons(), htonl() or htohs() functions.  It is implemented in the for(;;) loops.  You can verify it's true independent of the endiannes of the architecture.  Try and see.

Comment: Hello @LuisColorado, I saw that you have implemented manually. I just put it as a comment since I found this function last night while I was trying to solve it. Again thank you for your time and effort answering my question. As a beginner I have so many things to learn. I will update the question with the answer as soon as I found some time to work with it.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is quite old and no longer compiles on GCC 9.3.0 but it has inspired me to write a C++ equivalent, which makes conversions quite simple thanks to the chrono library:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using fractions = duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1, 0x100000000>>; // 1/(2^32)
using ntp_t = std::uint64_t;

auto tp2ntp(system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    // "shift" epoch from unix 1/1/1970 to ntp 1/1/1900 (70 years + 17 leap days)
    tp += (70 * 365 + 17) * 24h;

    auto total = tp.time_since_epoch();
    auto secs  = duration_cast<seconds>(total);
    auto fracs = duration_cast<fractions>(total - secs);

    return static_cast<ntp_t>( (secs.count() << 32) | fracs.count() );
}

auto ntp2tp(ntp_t ntp)
{
    auto tp = system_clock::time_point(); // epoch

    // "shift" epoch from ntp 1/1/1900 to unix 1/1/1970 (70 years + 17 leap days)
    tp -= (70 * 365 + 17) * 24h;

    tp += seconds(ntp >> 32);
    tp += duration_cast<system_clock::duration>( fractions(ntp & 0xffffffff) );

    return tp;
}

void print_tp(system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    auto total = tp.time_since_epoch();
    auto secs  = duration_cast<seconds>(total);
    auto usecs = duration_cast<microseconds>(total - secs);

    std::cout << "tp : " << secs.count() << '.' << usecs.count() << std::endl;
}

void print_ntp(ntp_t ntp)
{
    std::cout << "ntp: " << std::hex << (ntp >> 32) << '.' << (ntp & 0xffffffff) << std::dec << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto tp = system_clock::now();

    std::cout << "tp2ntp" << std::endl;
    auto ntp = tp2ntp(tp);
    print_tp(tp);
    print_ntp(ntp);

    std::cout << "ntp2tp" << std::endl;
    auto tp2 = ntp2tp(ntp);
    print_tp(tp2);
    print_ntp(ntp);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested by [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) in the comments, here is another version, which utilizes new data types added in C++20:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using fractions = duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1, 0x100000000>>; // 1/(2^32)
using ntp_t = std::uint64_t;

// difference between the unix epoch (1/1/1970) and the ntp epoch (1/1/1900)
constexpr auto epoch_diff = sys_days{ 1970y/1/1 } - sys_days{ 1900y/1/1 }; 

auto tp2ntp(system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    tp += epoch_diff; // shift epoch

    auto total = tp.time_since_epoch();
    auto secs  = duration_cast<seconds>(total);
    auto fracs = duration_cast<fractions>(total - secs);

    return static_cast<ntp_t>( (secs.count() << 32) | fracs.count() );
}

auto ntp2tp(ntp_t ntp)
{
    auto tp = system_clock::time_point();
    tp -= epoch_diff; // shift epoch

    tp += seconds{ ntp >> 32 };
    tp += duration_cast<system_clock::duration>( fractions{ ntp & 0xffffffff } );

    return tp;
}

void print_tp(system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    auto total = tp.time_since_epoch();
    auto secs  = duration_cast<seconds>(total);
    auto usecs = duration_cast<microseconds>(total - secs);

    std::cout << "tp : " << secs.count() << '.' << usecs.count() << std::endl;
}

void print_ntp(ntp_t ntp)
{
    std::cout << "ntp: " << std::hex << (ntp >> 32) << '.' << (ntp & 0xffffffff) << std::dec << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto tp = system_clock::now();

    std::cout << "tp2ntp" << std::endl;
    auto ntp = tp2ntp(tp);
    print_tp(tp);
    print_ntp(ntp);

    std::cout << "ntp2tp" << std::endl;
    auto tp2 = ntp2tp(ntp);
    print_tp(tp2);
    print_ntp(ntp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful. However, I hope you can clarify one aspect: for tp2ntp() shouldn't the ratio be <1000000, 0x100000000>? In simple words don't we also need to divide the fractional part by 1000000? Probably a similar comment applies to ntp2tp() as well. But right now, my focus is on tp2ntp().

Comment: @venk not sure I understand your question, but here's how it works. We take in `tp` and shift its epoch to 1/1/1900. Then count number of ticks in `total`. Ticks can be microsecs, millisecs or whatever (system dependent). Their length (aka, period) is part of the class signature of `total`. We call `duration_cast` and ask it to convert them ticks into 1-sec long ticks and store them in `secs`. The remaining ticks (`total - secs`) are converted into 1/(2^32) long ticks (ie, `fractions`) and are stored in `fracs`. Makes sense?

Comment: With C++20, there are new literals for year and day, so `(70 * 365 + 17) * 24h` could be shortened to `70y + 17d`.

Comment: @AaronWright true, they did add `std::chrono::days` and `std::chrono::years` in c++20 both of which are durations. However, the 'd' and 'y' literals return instances of [`std::chrono::day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/day) and [`std::chrono::year`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year) instead, which are not the same thing and do not mix with durations.

Comment: Correct, but you could also spell it: `tp += sys_days{1970y/1/1} - sys_days{1900y/1/1};`.  Not as concise, but easier to read.  You no longer even need the comment (imho).  And you no longer have to wonder if 17 is the correct number of leap days (it is).

Comment: @HowardHinnant the devil has spoken. ;) Thank you for the chrono library, Howard. I will update my answer.